# Perform sort-of "Single Signon" by share cookies between application in same web server

Tags: c#, .net, session, cookies, single-sign-on

I have several web application under the same server, each have its own login/pwd, session, cookies and ACL.  And I have db to link login in app A is the same person as login in app B.

What I want now is if Person X login app A, he/she can click a button in app A to go to app B without login in.

I have try to implement a encrypted cookies to share between apps, which in my case is possible after I put machine key in web.config.  My problem now is I want both apps have the same timeout.  If both apps have session timeout of 20 mins, I want session in app A keep alive even the client is keep on using apps B.  But I don't want to call a link in apps A on every request in apps B (Since we may extends to n apps)

Any ideas?

Comment: Is this a browser application (with web pages served by the server) or is it more like a phone app with a web service behind it?

Comment: @JohnWu Web application through IIS, accessed by browser

Comment: Usually in this situation you'd issue a more general cookie that can be used to create a new session (or resume an existing one, if it hasn't expired) on any of the sites without requiring the user to sign on. Would that be adequate? Or do you actually need to keep the session alive because there are state variables that need to be preserved?

Comment: I want to keep current structure of applications that each use their own sessions for their works, i.e. ACL.  My problem is how to keep them alive while user switching between application